# Windows Start button and task bar have stopped responding

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, start-menu

Ok, I admit I may be partially at fault for this one. The history of this problem is that my laptop has a hybrid drive, with a lovely big 1TB HDD (as advertised), and a pathetic, tiny little 138 GB SSD system drive. And of course, *every* blasted program wants to install itself and all its program data on the C drive, which meant that every week I had to do a manual cleanup of the cached files to stop my computer complaining that the C drive was full, while I had fully half a terabyte free on the D drive. So I did some skulduggery on the `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local` drive, making it a junction pointing at the D drive, and now I have a nice 20 GB cushion of free space on the system drive. Phew.

Only...unintended consequences. I can't 100% be sure, but I would guess this was when my Windows "Start" button stopped working. Whether I try click on it with the mouse, or push the "Windows" key on the keyboard, the Start menu simply does not appear. Furthermore, right-clicking on any item in the task bar no longer works (though left-clicking does), and I can't get the "Network" pop-up from the system tray to work at all, even from the Windows "Setup" form.

What might I have broken that could easily be fixed now, to get my Start menu working again?

Answer (score 0):

*So I did some skulduggery on the C:\Users\me\AppData\Local drive, making it a junction*

That generally does not work.

For reliable operation given the circumstances, you should back up your data to the other drive, then reinstall Windows.

This time install programs on the larger drive and keep data on the larger drive.

There are many folders and files in AppData used for many things. That is part of your User Profile. A damaged User Profile cannot be repaired and requires extensive work to fix it, if it can be fixed. That is a main reason for my suggestion.

Windows needs to be on drive C and USERS (the structure and User Profile above) needs to be on drive C. Email and documents can go on the other drive.

If you are willing, replace the SSD with a bigger drive. I have fully converted a while back. A goal is to have Windows, Programs and windows structures all on drive C and only data on the larger drive. This will be faster as well.

Comment: Why does the junction cause problems?

Comment: Also, you said, "This time install programs on the larger drive and keep data on the larger drive." Where is there an option to "keep data on the larger drive"? Even if I install programs to "D:\Program Files", everything still insists on storing AppData on the C drive!

Comment: There are many folders and files in AppData use for many things. That is part of your User Profile. A damaged User Profile cannot be repaired and requires extensive work to fix it, if it can be fixed. That is why I suggested what I did.

Comment: AppData does not hold programs (Program Files does that). AppData just holds USER data. My AppFolder (extensive manchine) is but 12 GB (email and docs elsewhere).  Move what you can move but not AppData